# Deserialization unknow json with Gson

Tags: java, android, gson

I got a free api for currency tracking with json: 
[api.coinmarketcap](https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v2/ticker/?limit=10)
I need deserialize this json to my compound java object with Gson library. This my model object:

```
public class Quote {
    @SerializedName("quotes")
    private String mName;
    @SerializedName("price")
    private double mPrice;

    public Quote(String name, double price) {
        mName = name;
        mPrice = price;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return mPrice;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class Currency {
    private int mId;
    private String mSymbol;
    private byte mRank;
    private String mWebsiteSlug;
    private int mMaxSupply;
    private Quote mQuote;

    public Currency(int id, String symbol, byte rank, String websiteSlug, int maxSupply) {
        mId = id;
        mSymbol = symbol;
        mRank = rank;
        mWebsiteSlug = websiteSlug;
        mMaxSupply = maxSupply;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getSymbol() {
        return mSymbol;
    }

    public byte getRank() {
        return mRank;
    }

    public String getWebsiteSlug() {
        return mWebsiteSlug;
    }

    public int getMaxSupply() {
        return mMaxSupply;
    }

    public Quote getQuote() {
        return mQuote;
    }
}
```

I can not deserialize with such nesting.

Comment: Please post the JSON content, and the error.

Comment: @sbso i cant. Stack Overlflow tell me: It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details. 
But nothing to say

Comment: It has key as value. It is difficult to parse this kind of Json and creating a POJO based on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I create currency deserializer:

```
public class CurrencyDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Currency> {
    @Override
    public Currency deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT, JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {

        Currency currency = new Currency();

        JsonObject currencyObject = json.getAsJsonObject();

        JsonElement id = currencyObject.get("id");
        if(!id.isJsonNull()) {
            currency.setId(id.getAsInt());
        }

        JsonElement name = currencyObject.get("name");
        if(!name.isJsonNull()) {
            currency.setName(name.getAsString());
        }

        JsonElement symbol = currencyObject.get("symbol");
        if(!symbol.isJsonNull()) {
            currency.setSymbol(symbol.getAsString());
        }

        JsonElement slug = currencyObject.get("website_slug");
        if(!slug.isJsonNull()) {
            currency.setWebsiteSlug(slug.getAsString());
        }

        JsonElement rank = currencyObject.get("rank");
        if(!rank.isJsonNull()) {
            currency.setRank(rank.getAsLong());
        }

        JsonElement circulatingSupply = currencyObject.get("circulating_supply");
        if(!circulatingSupply.isJsonNull()) {
            currency.setCirculatingSupply(circulatingSupply.getAsLong());
        }

        JsonElement totalSupply = currencyObject.get("total_supply");
        if(!totalSupply.isJsonNull()) {
            currency.setTotalSupply(totalSupply.getAsLong());
        }

        JsonElement maxSupply = currencyObject.get("max_supply");
        if(!maxSupply.isJsonNull()) {
            currency.setMaxSupply(maxSupply.getAsLong());
        }

        JsonElement lastUpdated = currencyObject.get("last_updated");
        if(!lastUpdated.isJsonNull()) {
            Long l = lastUpdated.getAsLong() * 1000;
            currency.setLastUpdated(new Date(l));
        }

        JsonObject quotes = currencyObject.get("quotes").getAsJsonObject();

        for(Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> rootObj : quotes.entrySet())
        {
            Quote quote = context.deserialize(rootObj.getValue(), Quote.class);
            quote.setName(rootObj.getKey());
            currency.addQuote(quote);
        }

        return currency;
    }
}
```

Simple and work

Answer (score 1):

You can use [enter link description here](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) to create your pojo classes from json

Comment: But there are too many husks here. I would like to custom deserializator or some. But i confused in the hierarchy

Comment: You can use this one https://gist.github.com/IamEgor/11bdc913bc9b0ba83bd9e80d8720e382

Comment: thank man. I did not know that could use Map <String, Currency> like this. For parse compound nesting